# Adding a child to a VBox component (FLEX)

Tags: apache-flex, vbox

First of all I wanted to thank in advance to everyone that reads this post.

I'm having a problem when adding a child to a `VBox` component. Is it not the same thing?:

List Item:

```
  <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
              public function addChildren():void {
                    var f:FaqItem=new FaqItem();
                    f.id="newUsersAssistance";
                    this.cont.addChild(f);
              }
        ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:VBox id="cont" width="100%"  borderThickness="0" verticalGap="0"/>
```

and:

```
<mx:VBox id="cont" width="100%"  borderThickness="0" verticalGap="0">
            <view:FaqItem id="newUsersAssistance" />
</mx:VBox>
```

I am injecting two properties (question and answer) to the `FaqItem` component from an auxiliar file (using BabelFX) that depends on the id of the `FaqItem`, but it is only working when I choose the second option. If I use the first option, I get a child but with the text in question and answer fields is empty. I need to use the first option.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks again for everything
Kind Regards

Comment: Could you show the code for the injection? I assume that BabelFX couldn't know when you're instantiating the new FaqItem(), so it doesn't know when to inject.

Comment: Is FaqItem a UIComponent (or a class that extends UIComponent)? It has to be to add as a child to a VBOX

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you will be able use the id property of the dynamically added component to do Injection. I suggest you keep some bindable variables to bind the value to the dynamic FaqItem.